# SSL sertificate does not work with safari

Tags: ssl, safari, ssl-certificate

my web site rezervation required ssl sertificate it works with 
firefox and chrome browsers but in safari id does not appear
what should i do for safari?
in chrome it works
in safari does not work
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your certificate seems to be [installed properly](http://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=sondakka.com)
What version of Safari are you using? it seems like you are using Safari for Windows, which is [loosing grounds](http://9to5mac.com/2013/09/19/farewell-windows-safari-as-apple-excludes-from-icloud-bookmark-sync/)
you might also want to check [this](http://www.sslshopper.com/article-safari-now-support-ev-ssl-certificates.html)
I'm not sure about Safari for Windows, though